# How to duplicate a stack from original stack

Tags: c, stack

I tried to write a c program which will have a function that returns a duplicate stack of the given stack. The duplicate stack contains the same elements as the original stack, and in the same order. The original stack must stay unchanged.
But I didn't get the desired output.The last two printf() outputs are not showed when running the code. The code terminates at the end of printf() command which shows the peak element of input stack.

```
void DuplicateStack(stack *s, stack *s1){
    int n;
    stack s3;
    CreateStack(&s3);
    while(!isEmpty(s)){
        n = pop(&s);
        push(&s3,n);
    }
    while(!isEmpty(&s3)){
        n = pop(&s3);
        push(&s,n);
        push(&s1,n);
    }
 }
  void main(){
     stack s,s1;
     CreateStack(&s);
    CreateStack(&s1);
    int num,n;
    printf("Enter no.of numbers you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        push(&s,n);
    }
    printf("Top element: %d\n",peek(&s));
    DuplicateStack(&s,&s1);
    printf("Top Element in the Original Stack: %d\n",peek(&s));
    printf("Top Element in the Duplicate Stack: %d\n",peek(&s1));
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `memcpy` suffice?

Comment: It could possibly be simpler, but it really depends on the implementation of the stack and if you control and can modify that implementation.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Only if stack implementation is based on arrays.

Comment: Off-topic: I see a `createStack` function, but not a `destroyStack` counterpart. Depending on implementation of your stack, that might (or not) result in a memory leak...

Answer (score 4):

It seems prototype of `push/pop` is as below.

```
void push (stack *, int);
void pop (stack *);
```

In that case you have undefined behavior.

```
    n = pop(&s);
    push(&s,n);
    push(&s1,n);
```

The above calls in `DuplicateStack` function are actually passing `stack **` to `push/pop` function instead of `stack *`. Since `s` and `s1` are already `stack *` , `&s` and `&s1` gives you the `stack **`.

Try changing them to.

```
void DuplicateStack(stack *s, stack *s1){
    int n;
    stack s3;
    CreateStack(&s3);
    while(!isEmpty(s)){
        n = pop(s);  // <<<-- &s to s
        push(&s3,n);
    }
    while(!isEmpty(&s3)){
        n = pop(&s3);
        push(s,n);   // <<<--- &s to s
        push(s1,n);  // <<<----&s1 to s1
    }
 }
```

Comment: Actually worse than pointer type not matching is that pointer addresses differ. Counter example: `print(int* array); int array[7]; print(&array);` – creating pointer of bad type, but that refers to correct address, and when converted back should run fine. Not sure if technically still UB, though.

Comment: @kiran Biradar
after changing the pointer as you mentioned, still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
`void binary(stack *s, int num){
    int n;
    while(num != 0){
        if(!isFull(s)){
            n = num % 2;
            push(s,n);
            num = num / 2;
        }
        else{
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

@kiran This is another code i made to convert a decimal number into binary number and store it on a stack. This code also deals with the same problem and terminates at that position too.Below is the minimal code of the original problem i have asked.

```
  while(!isEmpty(s)){
        n = pop(&s);
        c1 = c1 + 1;
        if(n%2 != 0)
            push(&s1,n);
    }
    while(!isEmpty(s1)){
        n = pop(&s1);
        push(&s,n);
        c2 = c2 + 1;
    }
```